# Standard term for the components of a distribution waterfall?

Tags: terminology

I'm writing software for calculating distribution waterfalls. When displaying the results of a particular calculation, I want to show amounts that correspond to specific provisions in the relevant LPA. When showing the distribution waterfall structure for a fund or other entity, I'd like to title the list of components of that structure. Is 'provision' the relevant term? Or is there another term that is used for these components?

My team is currently using the term 'tranch' ('tranche') internally, and it seems to at least roughly correspond to how that term is used, but it doesn't seem to be used when describing waterfalls.

Note that I'm not asking about a term or phrase for particular (standard) provisions, e.g. 'recovery phase', 'catchup phase', 'clawback'. I would like to know if a term (or phrase) covers all such possible components in general. The intended audience handles a wide variety of agreements with many different types of components, so I'd like to know of a term they'd recognize and readily understand.

Some candidates:

- Phase
- Provision
- Tranche

Comment: It depends on what the LPA stipulates. I worked in PE for couple of years and we would title the cash flow waterfall as "Cash-flow waterfall" and then name each component accordingly (e.g. Total released cashflow, investors cashflow up to subscribed capital, Investors up to hurdle, Mangt Company up to catch-up, etc.)

Comment: @volcompt I was just considering that, i.e. not bothering to title the components but just list them as-is. Or maybe I'll just title the set "waterfall structure".

Comment: I would have a title on top "Cashflow-Waterfall" or "Waterfall-Structure" and then name the names on the waterfall accordingly.

Comment: @volcompt Add an answer based on your comment and I'll up-vote (tho not accept yet).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what the LPA stipulates. I worked in PE for couple of years and we would title the cash flow waterfall as "Cash-flow waterfall" and then name each component accordingly (e.g. Total released cashflow, investors cashflow up to subscribed capital, Investors up to hurdle, Mangt Company up to catch-up, etc.)

Comment: I just noticed that *maybe* there's a little bit of confusion as to what I'm after. You write "It depends on what the LPA stipulates.". For all of the LPAs I've examined, the components are enumerated as "provisions", but that's probably because the LPA is a legal document and 'provision' is the relevant legal term. I'm not concerned with *legality* as much as familiarity (by users that are calculating distributions based on any number of possible waterfall structures).

Comment: All I mentioned above was "familiar" language such as to include in a presentation. I just checked the LPA of the last fund I worked on and the title for the cash waterfall legal points is: "Reimbursement of Capital and Distribution of income Policy".